# Flutter | How to Sort file list by creation time

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working in flutter app
i want get list of file in local Directory sorted by creation time

my list :

```
Directory appDirectory = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/myapp');
var fileList = [];
fileList = appDirectory.listSync().map((item) => item.path).where((item) => item.endsWith('.pdf')).toList(growable: false);
```

but the items in list sorted random .
How can i sort list by file creation time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, be aware that [`FileStat`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/FileStat-class.html) does not expose creation times, which isn't surprising since many filesystems don't store creation time and store only modification time.  If modification time is acceptable, you can call [`File.stat`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/FileSystemEntity/stat.html) for each `File`, collect the results, and sort by that.

```dart
var fileList = appDirectory.listSync().map((item) => item.path).where((item) => item.endsWith('.pdf')).toList(growable: false);

// Compute [FileStat] results for each file.  Use [Future.wait] to do it
// efficiently without needing to wait for each I/O operation sequentially.
var statResults = await Future.wait([
  for (var path in fileList) FileStat.stat(path),
]);

// Map file paths to modification times.
var mtimes = <String, DateTime>{
  for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i += 1)
    fileList[i]: statResults[i].changed,
};

// Sort [fileList] by modification times, from oldest to newest.
fileList.sort((a, b) => mtimes[a]!.compareTo(mtimes[b]!));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting the `fileList` by date-time attribute should do the trick

Example:

```
fileList.sort((a,b) {
    return DateTime.parse(a["dateTimeAttribute"]).compareTo(DateTime.parse(b["dateTimeAttribute"]));
});
```